# Swift 4: How to set only one word per row in an UITextView and create an array with each row

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview

I created an `UITextView` and I want to have only one word per row, so that each time I press the space dash it actually returns the text. How can I make the space button return instead of actually spacing the text? Plus, is there a way to record each word in order to create a custom array? 
This is my code right now:

```
@IBAction weak var wordView : UITextView!
@IBLabel weak var label : UILabel!

var words : [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let endEditingTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        endEditingTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(endEditingTapGesture)
}

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    getArray()
}

func getArray() {
    for _ in words {
        words.append(wordView.text)
    }
}
```

The button should add words to the array each time I press it... I'm not sure this is the best solution... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate if you're using taking input from same.

here is sample code.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = NSString(format: "%@", textView.text)
    var newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    newText = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "\n")
    newText = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "\n")

    textView.text = newText

    let myWordArr = textView.text.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    print(myWordArr)

    return false
}
```

don't forget to set delegate.

Comment: Ooookay! Works fine! just a question, what if I want to call myWordArr in my class (i put your code in an extension)?

Answer (score 0):

try this to replace space with new line use textView delegate method as below,

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    //checks if new text is white space
    if (text == " ") {
        if (textView.text?.characters.last == "\n") {
            // this will prevent multiple new lines
            return false
        }
        let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "\n")
         textView.text = newText
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

to get the array of all words

```
let allWords = yourTextView.text.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Comment: I tried adding an extension: extension ViewController : UITextViewDelegate{//your code inside} but it says 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly. So i now tried to change it to substring.text but it doesn't accept it. I tried to run it anyway but it still adds a space, what should I do?